# Como chamar uma procedure do form herdado através do form padrão?

Tags: delphi

Na minha aplicação feita em Delphi 7, é criado alguns objetos em Runtime no formulário padrão, como botões de manipular registro, procedimentos e funções comuns. Há um formulário padrão de consultas, outro para edição de registros e outro para relatórios. O formulário padrão de edição de registro possui a procedure "Salvar", nela possui o seguinte:

```
//Evento Salvar de FrmPadraoEdit
procedure TFrmPadraoEdit.Salvar(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ToolBar.Setfocus;
  //Demais instruções

  //deve continuar para a procedure Salvar do form herdado
end;
```

Como o botão "btnSalvar" também está no formulário padrão, o evento "Salvar" já é atribuído a ele.

Acontece que, para cada form herdado, o evento "Salvar" possui diferentes instruções. No formulário padrão, depois de chamar o evento "Salvar" dele próprio tem como dar continuidade nas instruções do evento "Salvar" do form herdado? Por ex:

```
//Evento Salvar de FrmDisciplinasEdit
procedure TFrmDisciplinasEdit.Salvar(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Aqui deveria continuar a execução

  DM.cdsDisciplinasATIVO.Value := 1;
  DM.cdsDisciplinasCREATED_BY.Value := V_LOGIN;
  //Demais instruções...
  DM.cdsDisciplinas.Post;
  Close;
end;
```

Comment: Então ele não executa a instrução: `DM.cdsDisciplinasATIVO.Value := 1;` ?

Comment: Não, pois só está sendo chamado a procedure Salvar do FrmPadraoEdit.

Comment: será que falta o override no cabeçalho do procedure TFrmDisciplinasEdit.Salvar(Sender: TObject); ?

Comment: opa, vou tentar e já posto o resultado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei como está a fazer a definiçao desses eventos, mas uma soluçao facil era tirar o codigo do click dos botoes e por num metodo seu.
No form padrao declarava

```
procedure DoSave; virtual;
```

com o codigo que é necessario chamar no padrao e chamava este no click do button

Nos forms herdados declarava este metodo

```
procedure DoSave; override;
```

e dentro deste o codigo que queria para cada form herdado. Para chamar o codigo do padrao usava o inherited. Algo como

```
procedure TFormHerdado.DoSave();
begin
   //Chamar save do form padrao
   inherited;
   //Codigo do form herdado
end
```

Comment: Exatamente Tiago, só que acrescentei também a diretiva "virtual" no procedimento do formulário padrão, pois nem estava compilando só com a diretiva "override" no formulário filho. Obrigado amigo pela resposta!

Comment: O problema agora é que quando chega no comando `Close;` para fechar o form filho, não acontece nada. É como se tivesse referenciando o form pai. Já tentei também `Self.Close;`, mas nada acontece. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Sinceramente nao... pode postar o header do form filho para ver como fez a herança e onde usa o close?

Comment: Opa, consegui resolver aqui, era só uma variável impedindo, mas já deu certo. Obrigado mais vez!